# Login script: Two if statements

Tags: php, database, hash, mysqli, password-hash

This code worked fine until I started hashing the passwords once the users signed up. I am using the standard function

```
password_hash()
```

This hashes my passwords in the users table. However, I noticed they couldn't login without another function verifying they are entering the right password. It tells me I have to use password_verify in a statement like this.

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
// Success!
}
else {
// Invalid credentials
}
```

However I already have an if statement in my login script and I am not sure how to combine the two. I've tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Login']) && (password_verify($password, $hash))){
```

But that doesn't work either. 
Can someone give me a suggestion on what I could do? Here is my entire login script (I've already connected to DB) and I just need to add the if statement for the hashed password.

```
if(isset($_POST['Login'])){


$Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Username']);
$UserPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['UserPassword']);
$sel_user = "select * from users where Username='$Username' AND UserPassword='$UserPassword'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);
$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

    if($check_user>0){
        session_start();
$_SESSION['Username']=$Username;

header('Location: index.php');
}

else {
            header('Location: login.php');
            echo "<p>". "Wrong password or username" . "</p>";

}
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "But that doesn't work either"? It will help people answer if you provide an error message to work from. Also, it seems like you're attempting to use $password and $hash before declaring them. Presumably you need to extract these values from your $_POST variable?

Comment: @Flyte Hello - what I mean by it doesn't work either is that it comes up with a blank page. I'll try fetching the variables through $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

You should check password provided by user with the hash stored in your database. 
So you have to do something likes this:

```
if (isset($_POST['login']) {
   //check for if password is provided
   //some code to verify user login in database and if exists get password      
   //hash for this login like this
   $query = mysqli_query($con,"select hash from users where   
   username=".$login); //or some error proccessing
   if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
     //incorrect login proccesing
   }
   $hash = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)['hash'];
   if (!password_verify($password,$hash)) {
    //wrong passsword proccesing
   }
}
```